# LINQ to SQL ToList() is creating duplicates and dropping entries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

In my code I am trying to populate a User Defined Table with the contents of a table. Currently I am pulling the contents of a SQL table into a list using LINQ to SQL and then converting that list into a DataTable to be used as the UDT parameter. I encountered an error on this where the DataTable ended up with duplicate entries and was missing some entries that existed in the original SQL table.

I broke down the process and identified the issue was occurring when generating the original List from the SQL table.

In the attached image you can see I use linq to see if a specific record exists in db.job_41000s. Then I print the result to output, it came up as True. After that I pulled db.job_4100s into a List variable joblist. Then I searched joblist with linq to find the same specific record and wrote the results to the output window and it came back false.

How can this occur?

[image: See Picture]

~Edit:

This screenshot shows the generated SQL query from the linq statements. Nothing looks out of the ordinary to me. For what it's worth, both results SHOULD be 'True'. The record definitely exists in the SQL server.

[image]

I solved the issue, though I would still like to know why this broke it if anyone has any idea.  The job_41000 mapping didn't have ID as a primary key. Correctly setting this to be part of the primary key fixed the issue. However I don't understand why not having this as a primary key would cause the ToList function to behave oddly.

Comment: Keep in mind case sensitivity. Most of the time the database is set up to ignore case on querying while in memory compares are case sensitive by default to say it simply.

Comment: This is most likely due to a difference between the way that SQL compares items and the way .NET compares items in-memory. For example, it's possible that your database is set to do string comparisons in a case-insensitive way, whereas C#'s `==` is case-sensitive.

Comment: I added another image to show the generated SQL Query. In this case the 'case' used is exactly as shown. It is stored as DC14-040001751 in SQL Server. 

I'm trying to take data from SQLServerA, table Jobs and put it into SQLServerB, table Jobs. Doing something like 'Insert into SQLA.jobs SELECT * FROM SQLB.jobs' took far too long over a VPN and a solution was to create a procedure on SQLB that accepted a User Defined Table.

When I ran the process in this case, it took the data from Jobs in SQLA and failed on a duplicate key error when trying to input it into SQLB. They have identical indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by not having the ID field marked as IsPrimaryKey=True. After correctly marking that the ToList() method no longer behaved oddly.